# does $\phi(-1) = -1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are not isomorphic when considered groups under multiplication.

My idea was to show that there is no real number that square to $-1$.

Suppose an isomorphism existed between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\phi(x) = i$. Then $\phi(x^2) = \phi(x)\phi(x) = i^2 = -1$.

If I could show that $\phi(-1) = -1$ then I could use injectivity of $\phi$ to come to a contradiction, but I am not sure if this is true or how to show it.

Comment: You must mean $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{*}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In both groups $-1$ is the unique element of order 2.

But it may be easier just to show that $\mathbb C^\times$ contains an element of order $3$ and $\mathbb R^\times$ doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb C$ has an element of order $4 $ namely $i$ but $\mathbb R$ has no element of order $4$